# Assembly language - Flag setting giving me headaches

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, cpu-registers

I'm trying to determine what various flags should be set to (carry, sign, zero, overflow) after the following operation:

```
mov ax, 7ff0h;       ax register is now 7ff0h

add al, 10h;
```

I'm confused as to how assembly handles this. since we are adding to just the al portion of the register which contains `f0h`, `f0h + 10h` gives `100h`. Does this set the overflow flag? The carry flag? Neither? I would think the overflow flag would be set, however, another possibility running through my mind is that the program detects this and automatically alters the ah register from `7fh` to `80h`, making the full `ax` register `8000h`. This would in theory not set the carry flag, but would instead set the sign flag and overflow flag because our overall number `8000h` is now negative. could anyone explain how this is handled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played a bit with the debug command (shipped with x86 Windows):

```
-a 100
1A2F:0100 mov ax, 7ff0
1A2F:0103 add al, 10
1A2F:0105
-t =100 2

AX=7FF0  BX=0000  CX=0000  DX=0000  SP=FFEE  BP=0000  SI=0000  DI=0000
DS=1A2F  ES=1A2F  SS=1A2F  CS=1A2F  IP=0103   NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC
1A2F:0103 0410          ADD     AL,10

AX=7F00  BX=0000  CX=0000  DX=0000  SP=FFEE  BP=0000  SI=0000  DI=0000
DS=1A2F  ES=1A2F  SS=1A2F  CS=1A2F  IP=0105   NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE CY
1A2F:0105 0000          ADD     [BX+SI],AL                         DS:0000=CD
-
```

NV  [No Overflow]
PL (positive)
CY  [Carry]

Answer (score 1):

From the Intel instruction manual on the `ADD` instruction:

> The ADD instruction performs integer addition. It evaluates the result for both signed
>   and unsigned integer operands and sets the OF and CF flags to indicate a carry (overflow)
>   in the signed or unsigned result, respectively. The SF flag indicates the sign of
>   the signed result.

Running the a simple test in a debugger, we can see the CF flag is set, and only the bits that form AL are changed:

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT

.STACK 1024

ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dwExitCode:DWORD

.CODE
_start:
    XOR EAX,EAX
    MOV AX,7ff0h
    ADD AL,10h
    PUSH 0  ;EAX is now 0x00007F00
    CALL ExitProcess

PUBLIC _start
END
```